# how to isolate scope using directive call a method from directive to controller and method using arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is my sample angularjs code .currently i can't get the item name which i clicked . i passed argument name attribute inside method from directive template. That method i used in parent controller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<style>
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
   -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 20px; padding: 0; line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 8px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #D1D0CE ; color: #AB9ED9;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}

</style>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script> 
    
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var app = angular.module('mainapp', []); 

app.controller('check', function($scope) { 
     $scope.selData=[];
  $scope.sel="tt";
     $scope.fruits = [{'name':'apple','status':false},
                   {'name':'orange','status':false},
                   {'name':'pear','status':false},
       {'name': 'naartjie','status':false}];
     
 
  $scope.check=function(val){
  alert(val);
  }
  });
app.directive('slidecheckbox', function() { 
 var directive = {};
    directive.restrict   = 'A';
    directive.template  = '<table><tr ng-repeat="fruitName in slide"><td>{{fruitName.name}}</td><td><label><div class="onoffswitch">'+
                               '<input type="checkbox" name="{{fruitName.name}}" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"  value="{{fruitName.name}}" ng-checked="fruitName.status"'+
          'x-ng-click="test()">'+
                               '<label class="onoffswitch-label"><span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span><span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span></label></div> '+ 
                                '</label></td></tr> </table>';   
 directive.scope    = {
         slide: "=obj",
         test:"&"
          }; 
 
    return directive;
});
   
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainapp">
<div  ng-controller="check">
 <div style="width:175px; height:150px;overflow: auto;border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;" slidecheckbox obj="fruits" test="check()"></div>

 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

please someone help me out ..

Answer (score 0):

You have the ng-click on the input but the input is being hidden by

```
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want the click to work put it on the following tag

```
<label class="onoffswitch-label"  ng-click="test()">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWYqTbaZlZBY8PE0l3BQ?p=preview)